# Creating new MouseWheelEventArgs for Global Mouse Hook

Tags: c#, wpf

As per MSDN below is the MouseWheelEventArgs constructor

```
public MouseWheelEventArgs(
    MouseDevice mouse,
    int timestamp,
    int delta
)
```

This is a method from my Global Mouse Hook that I am trying to complete:

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages)wParam)
    {
        MouseDevice mouseDev = InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice;

        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

        //Initializes a new instance of the MouseWheelEventArgs class using the specified MouseDevice, timestamp, and delta.
        MouseAction(null, new MouseWheelEventArgs(mouseDev, timestamp, delta));
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

What I'm looking for is:

Timestamp - it is fine to just generate current date time on the fly?

delta - you must be able to programmatically get this from the mouse device somehow, but how?

Comment: Thankyou! this was tricky to find online, could you pop this in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/MouseDevice.cs#339) can show you that the `timestamp` is retrieved from "Environment.TickCount`.

The [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for MSLLHOOKSTRUCT can show you that the `delta` is passed as the upper word of the MSLLHOOKSTRUCT.mouseData element.  Make sure that you declared that member as *int*, not as *uint*, so that sign extension works properly.

Thus:

```
   int timestamp = Environment.TickCount;
   int delta = hookStruct.mouseData >> 16;
   MouseAction(null, new MouseWheelEventArgs(mouseDev, timestamp, delta));
```